# Print the type of object using Iterator

Tags: java

I write a method for printing the type of the object which not working properly. The idea is to read the input, insert them in the ArrayList and then, print their types. I would like to provide the input as follow

```
42
3.1415
Welcome to Hackerrank Java tutorials!
```

and eventually, get the output in the reverse order such as

```
String: Welcome to Hackerrank Java tutorials!
Double: 3.1415
Int: 42
```

It always come in the serial as int, double and String. The method is provided below  with one solution.  I'm trying to solve it with BufferedReader now.

```
public static void printMethod ( ){


        List<Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int count = 0; 

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

        count++; 

        String line = scan.nextLine();

        if( count == 1 ){

            try {

                Integer v = Integer.valueOf(line.trim());
                arr.add(v);
                continue;
            } 

            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

            }
        }

        if ( count == 2 ){

            try {

                Double d = Double.valueOf(line.trim());
                arr.add(d);
                continue;
            } 

            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

            }
        }
        arr.add(line);            
    }

    for (int i = arr.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        Object obj = arr.get(i);
        Class<?> type = obj.getClass();

        String[] s = type.getName().toString().split("\\.") ;

        if ( s[s.length - 1 ].equals("Integer") )
            System.out.println( "Int" + ": " +obj.toString());

        else 
            System.out.println(s[s.length - 1 ] + ": " +obj.toString());

        // System.out.println( );

    }  

    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: readLine() returns a string.  All your array elements will be of type String.

Comment: move `value = br.readLine()` into the while loop

Comment: But, the value is an Object. How it will be String ? I would like to solve the problem using BufferedReader

Comment: public String readLine()
                throws IOException
Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
Returns:
A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Comment: Will the input always be String, then Double, then Int? if not I'm not sure you can accomplish it

Comment: No, it wil be random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you will need to parse the supported types. Since your question lists `Integer`, `Double` and `String` I'll show you a way you might parse those. Also, I'd use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Putting that together, it might look something like

```
List<Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    try {
        Integer v = Integer.valueOf(line.trim());
        arr.add(v);
        continue;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    try {
        Double d = Double.valueOf(line.trim());
        arr.add(d);
        continue;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    arr.add(line);
}
for (int i = arr.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Object obj = arr.get(i);
    Class<?> type = obj.getClass();
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", type.getName(), obj.toString());
}
```

Which I ran (and received your expected output) lke

```
42
3.1415
Welcome to Hackerrank Java tutorials!
java.lang.String: Welcome to Hackerrank Java tutorials!
java.lang.Double: 3.1415
java.lang.Integer: 42
```